# Tell std::unordered_map that the hash function is perfect

Tags: c++, std, unordered-map

Would it be possible to tell `std::unordered_map` that the hash function is perfect?

Thus, if two different keys yield the same hash code, they edit the same slot of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making the `operator==` yield a comparison with the hashes instead of the attributes, will cause `std::unordered_map` to assume they are equal.

Comment: This probably just results in the hash function to be called more often. Usually equality is cheaper to implement than a hash function. I don't see how this would result in better optimization of the map data structure.

Comment: @fabian I hadn't thought of that, but since my hash function promotes collisions in order to edit the same slots, it's actually a pretty quick and simple one.

Answer (score 2):

Hash function being perfect is not enough. It is possible that values that generate different hash-values are mapped to the same slot in the hash table. For example, the size of container might be 11, one of your hash values can be 12 and the other can be 23. Assuming the container uses modulus operator to map these values, they would both be mapped to to slot number 1. So, you need a way to differentiate these later on.

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with setting `KeyEqual` template paratemer of `std::unordered_map` to `[](const auto& l,const auto& r){return true;}` as it should only be used when hashes compare equal.